# How to select element that doesn't exist yet (jQuery) and change its style?

Tags: jquery, select, colors, element, live

Below is my code. I'd like to change background color of #preview div but it always fails to select #preview. It seems that it doesn't exist when script executes. Other jQuery script creates it later on.

```
jQuery("#panel").mouseleave(function(){
    var good_color = jQuery('.colorpicker_hex input').val();
    jQuery("#preview").css({ 'background-color': good_color });
});
```

How do I select all current and future #preview divs and change their background colors? I think that there's something like live() but I haven't found example with CSS change yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery doesn't specifically have anything to do what you've listed. You can add a `style` element to do it, though:

```
$("<style>#preview { background-color: #eee; }</style>")
    .appendTo(document.documentElement);
```

Like all style rules, that will apply as and when any elements match it. As you're adding it at the end of the document element, it should win any style conflicts (barring specificity differences, but `id` selectors are pretty specific).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ayoyoz) - Tested and working in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE6, and IE9

Answer (score 2):

You can not. Basically jQuery nevigate via DOM tree to select proper object. 
So, run script after document loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#panel").mouseleave(function(){
        var good_color = jQuery('.colorpicker_hex input').val();
        jQuery("#preview").css({ 'background-color': good_color });
    });
});
```

`#panel` or `#preview` might not exist in your case.

Answer (score 1):

`live()` (which is now deprecated, so you should use `on()` instead) is just for events. There is no way to select an element which doesn't yet exist. However, you can create an element like this:

```
var previewDiv = $('<div id="#preview" />');
```

And this div isn't yet attached to your document. You can manipulate its CSS as you please with:

```
previewDiv.css({ 'background-color': good_color });
```

Then your script which was previously responsible for creating the script can just attach it instead:

```
previewDiv.appendTo(parentElement);
```